# insert nothing instead of something sql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I've got the following issue.

When typing that, I have a zero as a result

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies))
FROM 
table_repo3 WHERE
url LIKE '%easyeasy%'
GROUP BY cur_date;
```

But when typing below, no lines are inserted.

```
INSERT INTO toto (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT '2B1',CURRENT_DATE AS cur_date,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) =0 
              THEN 111 
            ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) 
       END
FROM 
table_repo3 WHERE
url LIKE '%easyeasy%'
GROUP BY cur_date;
```

When typing that, I have nothing as well.

```
SELECT '2B1',CURRENT_DATE AS cur_date,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) = 0 
               THEN 111 
             ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) 
        END
FROM 
table_repo3 WHERE
url LIKE '%easyeasy%'
GROUP BY cur_date;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure there are any entries? Does `SELECT * FROM table_repo3 WHERE url LIKE '%easyeasy%'` get you any results?

Comment: Nothing. Not zero, just plain nothing. I tried with `IS NULL` but it did not do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean "zero as a result"? You get no results set?

Comment: Yes Peter,  no results set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want the `GROUP BY` in your statement.  If it was successfully able to aggregate by cur_date then you'd insert multiple records with the ID 281.  Assuming ID is the primary key in your table, then you'll get an error.

If you remove the `GROUP BY` you'll get a count of all distinct cookies with a matching Url.

```
INSERT INTO toto (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT '2B1',CURRENT_DATE AS cur_date,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) =0 
    THEN 111 
    ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT(cookies)) END
FROM table_repo3
WHERE url LIKE '%easyeasy%'
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, many thanks and sorry for my belated reply. But let's say that I need that `GROUP BY`. What should I do?